# Error: Unable to get property 'createEncryptor' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, cryptography

```
function generateload_Click(form1)
{
    window.text="Thishasto";
    window.key = "hello";
    var useHashing = true;
    var encrypted;
    if (useHashing){
        key = CryptoJS.MD5(key).toString();
    }

    window.options = {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    };

    window.textWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text);
    window.keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);

    window.encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(textWordArray, keyHex, options);

    alert(encrypted);
}
```

returns the below error when run in IE

> Error: Unable to get property 'createEncryptor' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: ECB is insecure and MD5 is not a password based key derivation mechanism. Use AES, not 3DES.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem [here](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/issues/detail?id=136). Resolved by including each mode and padding source files.

Comment: can you explain in details please?

Comment: I figured it out. but the encrypted value is different from  C#

Comment: how were you able to figure it out, please?

Comment: Change the mode to CryptoJS.mode.CBC and works for me.